# Firefox Selenium test freezes sometimes

Tags: firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium 2.46 and Firefox 31. Whenever my test gets to a point that an web-element does not exist (or an exception is thrown) my test freezes, but it does not happen when I use Chrome. Just to let you know I have already used different versions of selenium-java and Firefox. Please find the code below:

```
List<WebElement> divs = driverChrome.findElements(By.tagName("div"));
int i = 0;
while (true) {
    boolean breakIt = true;
    System.out
            .println("Waiting for map to load completely, thanks for your patience.");
    for (WebElement weDiv : divs) { 
        try {       
            if (weDiv.getText().equals("Loading")) {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                breakIt = false;
                break;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
    if (breakIt) {
        break;
    } 
    driverChrome.manage().timeouts()
            .implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    divs = driverChrome.findElements(By.tagName("div"));

}
```

I am using this code to wait till a map is completely loaded

Comment: Have you tried to upgrade Firefox to the latest version?

Comment: @alecxe yes, it did not work

Comment: Please show what code are you executing.

Comment: @alecxe and I have to use firefox because I need action.dragandDrop() and it does not work for Chrom :(

Comment: @user4966430 Action.dragandDrop() works in Chrome too

Answer (score 1):

The most probable reason for your test to freeze is the `while(true)` loop. If the text "Loading" does not show up, there still can be an (invisible) element with that text.

Anyway, I would never use a wait mechanism without timeout. And I would always try to use methods provided by the framework.

WebDriver offers [explicit and implicit wait mechanisms](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits). This one-liner could replace your whole listing (waits for up to 60s, polling every two seconds):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 60000L, 2000L).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementWithText(By.tagName("div"), "Loading"));
```

Hope it helps. If not, check out other methods of `ExpectedConditions` or implement your own `ExpectedCondition`.